# C++ Asks the user for a series of integers one at a time and when the user enters the integer 0, the program shows some info about the inputs

Tags: c++

How can I write a program that asks the user for a series of integers one at a time and when the user enters the integer 0, the program displays the following info

the number of integers in the series

the average of the integers

the largest integer in the series

the smallest integer in the series

the difference between the largest and smallest integer in the series

Tried searching up online for solutions but could not find what I'm looking for

Comment: Seems to be a very straight forward exercise. What have you attempted so far? What are you stuck on? Please be more specific. Do you know how to code a loop? How to read user input? How to use variables? How to mathematically calculate the kind of values you are asked for? Break the project down into smaller tasks. We are here to answer *specific* questions about coding, not to do your homework for you. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/).

Comment: Is this a classroom exercise?

Comment: I got it figured it out now

Comment: yeah it is lol.

Comment: Then you do know that when you hand in this assignment, you *better* know everything about the code that you accepted as an answer.  Your teacher, if they are competent, *will* ask you questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel generous:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    int number;
    vector<int> database;
    cout << "Enter a number, 0 == quit: ";
    while (cin >> number)
    {
        if (number == 0) break;
        database.push_back(number);
        cout << "Enter a number, 0 == quit: ";
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above code performs the fundamentals.
The remaining requirements are left as an exercise for the OP.

For those who are allergic to containers:

```
#include <iostream>  

int main()
{
    int largest = 0;
    int smallest = 0;  
    std::cout << "Enter number, 0 to quit: ";
    std::cin >> largest;
    smallest = largest;
    if (largest == 0) return EXIT_SUCCESS;  
    int quantity = 1;
    int number;
    int sum = largest;
    std::cout << "Enter number, 0 to quit: ";
    while (std::cin >> number)
    {
        if (number == 0) break;
        largest = (number > largest) ? number : largest;
        smallest = (number < smallest) ? number : smallest;
        ++quantity;
        sum += number;
        std::cout << "Enter number, 0 to quit: ";
    }
    const double average = static_cast<double>(sum) / quantity;
    std::cout << "Average:  " << average << "\n";
    std::cout << "Largest:  " << largest << "\n";
    std::cout << "Smallest: " << smallest << "\n";
    std::cout << "Quantity: " << quantity << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Remaining requirements are responsibility of the OP.  The above is an example of a "running sum" or performing the calculations without using a container.

Comment: I can provide more code, but I'll need information on how to submit the code and the deadline.  Also, your real name or student ID would be nice, so you can get credit for my code.  No freebies.

Comment: Nothing in the question requires storing data and it seems unlikely the OP has been taught what `std::vector` even is.

Comment: In most of these requirements, the developers use a container, then after data is input, perform analysis on the container.  "On the fly" seems to be an advanced topic. :-(

Comment: is using namespace std not ideal for this?

Comment: As much as I love `vector` the problem requires only min,max,sum, and count.

Comment: I'm only including the headers I need, and stating the symbols in `std` namespace that I will be using.  No need to bring in more than what's needed.

Comment: Very wise and judicious use of explicit `using` statements for only the specific symbols desired.  `using namespace std;` is the mindkiller.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews -- I would leave the code as-is.  If the student just hands in the code to the teacher, it's going to be the student's troubles if they cannot explain the code to the teacher.